# Priority queue in Java?

Tags: java, priority-queue

Is it possible in Java to create a PriorityQueue of objects where the key that decides the priority is the member of the object?

All the examples I see on net insert an integer into the PriorityQueue and retrieve them. I'm looking for an implementation that would insert an instance of an object and is retrieved based on one of its member values, which might be an integer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, `PriorityQueue` has a [constructor](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) that allows you to a pass a `Comparator` to define the order of the elements. For example, if you have the following `Bar` class:

```
public class Bar {
  private int priority;

  // getters / setters ...
}
```

And you want to create a priority queue that orders the elements based on the `priority` field (e.g., items with greater priority stay in the front of the queue), you can use the following:

```
Queue<Bar> queue = new PriorityQueue<Bar>(new Comparator<Bar>() {
  public int compare(Bar a1, Bar a2) {
    return a2.getPriority() - a1.getPriority(); // adapt this to your needs
  }
});
```

If you have more complex logic in the `compare` method, or if you want to reutilize the code, then I suggest you create a class, say `BarComparator`, that implements `Comparator<Bar>`.

Also, as an alternative to the above, you can make `Bar` implement the `Comparable` interface, and use the [empty](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28%29) constructor, like so:

```
public class Bar implements Comparable<Bar> {
  private int priority;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Bar b) {
    return b.getPriority() - this.priority;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: when you say ordering by greater priority do you mean in the sense that a Bar with priority 3 has a greater priority then a Bar with priority 13, in the sense that Bar's that have a smaller priority value actually have a "greater priority"

Comment: The exact opposite. A `Bar a` with a priority 20 has a greater priority than a `Bar b` with priority 18, and thus, `Bar a` stays in the front of the queue.